# Entity Framework and database column names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco

I'm trying to modify a POCO T4 template to include the name of the column in the database that corresponds to each property.  For legacy reasons, our database tables are 8.3, and our columns are max 10 characters, so things tend to get abbriviated.  Being able to quickly look up which column a given property corresponds to will be a big help.

Given that, I have no clue how to go about doing this.  I'm comfortable with the idea of editing the T4 template, I just don't know how to retreive the column name from an EdmProperty object.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm assuming edmProperty.Name is not what you mean. You want the underlying column name.

Answer (score 1):

I've already discussed this in some other answer but I can't find it know. The problem is that to get this information you need to browse MSL part of the mapping - the part where columns are mapped to properties. Unfortunately whole API for MSL metadata items is internal (I think one goal for future EF release is to make it public). When you have T4 template for class generation you normally work with CSDL - that is entity description and it contains only information you see in the EDMX diagram and property window for entities.

Comment: It's not even available in MetadataWorkspace?  Several other answers seemed to indicate that it was, although I couldn't figure out how to get at it in the T4.

Comment: It is avaliable in MetadataWorkspace but queries on the workspace returns base items and you must cast them to get access to data you are looking for. The problem with MSL is that you cannot cast it because those types are not public - you must use reflection to get those data.

Comment: I'd be happy with an answer that used reflection, assuming reflection is available when the T4 is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I won't say this is the best way about solving this problem, but this is how I did it. I needed to be able to retrieve the the column names in plaintext for binding to BoundField asp controls, and that wasn't baked into the EF template.

So, I added this bit of code which just loads the "simple properties", ie: the column names, to allow me to do that. It adds a struct to the "table" object called "ColumnNames" and exposes the column names as const strings.

```
<#
    if (simpleProperties.Any())
    {
#>
    public struct ColumnName 
    {
  <# 
      foreach (var simpleProperty in simpleProperties)
      {
  #>
      public const string <#= simpleProperty #> = "<#= simpleProperty #>";
  <# 
      }
  #>
  }
<#  }
#>
}
```

I placed this before this bit of code in the T4 template that generates the individual files under the edmx file in the solution:

```
<#
    EndNamespace(code);
}
```

That will create code that looks like this:

```
public partial class JobPosting
{
    public int PositionRowId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid PositionRelatedGuid { get; set; }

    public struct ColumnName 
    {
        public const string PositionRowId = "PositionRowId";
        public const string PositionRelatedGuid = "PositionRelatedGuid";
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have that code in front of me, but doesn't `simpleProperties` give you the names based on the `edmx` file?  If the column is called `myColumnID` in the database, but I've renamed it in the designer to `MyColumnId` for C# consistency's sake, which name shows up here?

Comment: As far as I know, and I learned EF yesterday so I could be wrong, it's based on the edmx file, so if you rename it in the designer then it shows up with the edmx name, and not the database name, in the result.

Comment: That's what I thought.  This is definitely a good solution, but to a different problem then I was having. My question was specifically about how to retrieve the underlying database name even after renaming it.  I'm pretty much convinced it isn't possible, but I encourage you to leave this answer here to help anyone else who finds this question.

Comment: I think the question of how possible it is depends a lot on your workflow, but if I was going to go to the bother (starting from nothing like I am now) to rename fields coming out of a database into some sort of sanity, then I would probably manually create another partial class for JobPosting with a second public struct that maps to the first struct with sensible names, and change the first struct to privately accessible. So I would then have something like JobPosting.PublicColumnName that returns JobPosting.PrivateColumnName values, which then correspond to the database fields.